# Multiple image upload worked but only once

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view to view images after uploading them as follows:

```
    @model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Model.Image>
@using MvcApplication1.Models

<div id="divImages">




    <input type="file" id="FileUpload" multiple />
    <input type="submit" id="Upload" value="Upload" />

    <table class="table" id="tble">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.cover)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Product.type)
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cover)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.Image("/Images/" + item.id_product + "/" + item.id_image + ".jpg", "Image", "50")
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.id_image })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
</div>
```

and the ajax as follows:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Upload").click(function () {
            var formData = new FormData($('form').get(0));
            var totalFiles = document.getElementById("FileUpload").files.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++)
            {
                var file = document.getElementById("FileUpload").files[i];

                formData.append("FileUpload", file);
            }
            formData.append("Model", @Model.Take(1).Single().id_product);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Products/Upload',
                data: formData,
                //dataType: 'json',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    alert('succes!!');
                    $.get('@Url.Action("All", "Products")', { id: @Model.Take(1).Single().id_product }, function (data) {
                        $("#divImages").html(data);
                    });
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert("errror");
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

You can see after alerting the user of successful uploading, the partial view is updated.

Here's my `Upload()` function:

```
    public ActionResult Upload(int model)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
        {
            Image p = new Image();
            p.cover = true;
            p.id_product = model;
            db.Images.Add(p);
            db.SaveChanges();
            var ims = db.Images.OrderByDescending(x => x.id_image).Take(1).Single(); 
            var file = Request.Files[i];
            var fileName = ims.id_image.ToString() + ".jpg"; //Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Server.MapPath("~/Images/"+model.ToString()+"/");
            if(this.CreateFolderIfNeeded(path))
                file.SaveAs(path + fileName);
        }


        return RedirectToAction("All", new { id = model }); 
    }
```

and finally, my `All()` function:

```
    public PartialViewResult All(int id)
    {
        List<Image> model = db.Images.Where(x => x.id_product == id).ToList();
        if (model.Count() == 0)
        {
            Image i = new Image();
            i.id_product = id;
            List<Image> li = new List<Image>();
            li.Add(i);
            return PartialView("_File", li);
        }
        else
            return PartialView("_File", model); 
    }
```

and here's my `Image` model:

```
namespace WebApplication1.Model
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Image
    {
        public int id_image { get; set; }
        public int id_product { get; set; }
        public bool cover { get; set; }

        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and the Edit view:

```
@model WebApplication1.Model.Product
@using MvcApplication1.Models

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<head>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="jquery.fileupload.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
    <h2>Edit</h2>

    <br />
    <br />


    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#fragment-1"><span>Information</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#fragment-2"><span>Prices</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#fragment-3"><span>SEO</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#fragment-4"><span>Associations</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#fragment-5"><span>Images</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id_product)
                <div id="fragment-1">

                </div>

                <div id="fragment-2">


                </div>

                <div id="fragment-3">


                </div>


            <div id="fragment-4">

            </div>

            <div id="fragment-5">


                    @{ Html.RenderAction("All", "Products", new { id = Model.id_product }); }

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    }

    <script src="external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '/Products/UploadFiles',
                autoUpload: true,
                done: function (e, data) {
                    $('.file_name').html(data.result.name);
                    $('.file_type').html(data.result.type);
                    $('.file_size').html(data.result.size);
                }
            }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $('.progress .progress-bar').css('width', progress + '%');
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

Now, everything worked well that is uploading and refreshing the partial view. Except when after successful uploading, when I want to upload another image, the upload button doesn't work.

I hope some know why.

Comment: Any error messages to share? check the console on your browser

Comment: What do you mean by the "upload button" doesn't work? I presume you mean it's still clickable but your action method isn't being called in which case it's likely a problem your jQuery.

Also check console for errors after you upload files.

Comment: @MartinMazzaDawson you get me correctly.  no error in the console

Comment: Where is your element with `"#divImages"` in the view. If the partial view your returning contains your 'Upload' submit button, then you need to use event delegation. And your using ajax, and ajax calls do not redirect, so you use of `return RedirectToAction("All", new { id = model }); ` does not make sense.

Comment: And rather that returning all images, you should be returning only those images you have just saved and then updating the existing table (either as a partial view, or a json containing a collection of the image paths.

Comment: Also suggest you show your `Image` model - there are lot of potential failure points in the code you have shown.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I added my Image model up

Comment: @StephenMuecke "#divImages" is in the main view. I tried to make it in the partial view but no use.

Comment: And is the model in the view `@model IEnumerable<Image>`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the main view and I will add an answer showing how to solve your immediate issue (the button click). But I will also update it later to solve some of the other issues your going to face.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I added the main view. I edited the partial view as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106668/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-aymen-kareem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved after removing the following section from the main view. Many thanx to Stephen Muecke.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '/Products/UploadFiles',
                autoUpload: true,
                done: function (e, data) {
                    $('.file_name').html(data.result.name);
                    $('.file_type').html(data.result.type);
                    $('.file_size').html(data.result.size);
                }
            }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $('.progress .progress-bar').css('width', progress + '%');
            });
        });
    </script>
```